# codeigniter, Using Case When for Where Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query which i want to make it work in codeigniter query form, so want to know if its possible or not.

This is the query i want to implement in Codeigniter in codeigniter's own way.

```
    use zorkif_next;
SELECT 
    `osp_job_status_track`.`StatusID`,
    `osp_job_status_track`.`SubStatusID`,
    `osp_job_sub_status`.`CurrentStatus`
FROM
    (`osp_job_details`)
        LEFT JOIN
    `osp_job_status_track` ON `osp_job_status_track`.`JobID` = `osp_job_details`.`JobID`
        LEFT JOIN
    `osp_job_status` ON `osp_job_status`.`StatusID` = `osp_job_status_track`.`StatusID`
        LEFT JOIN
    `osp_job_sub_status` ON `osp_job_sub_status`.`SubStatusID` = `osp_job_status_track`.`SubStatusID`
        LEFT JOIN
    `hr_employee_details` ON `hr_employee_details`.`EmployeeID` = `osp_job_details`.`AssignToEmployeeID`
        LEFT JOIN
    `osp_job_type` ON `osp_job_type`.`JobTypeID` = `osp_job_details`.`JobtypeID`
WHERE
    -- `isDefault` = 1
       --    AND 

    CASE WHEN `osp_job_status`.`StatusID` = 2 
    THEN  `osp_job_sub_status`.`CurrentStatus` = 3
    ELSE `osp_job_status`.`StatusID` >= 2
    END ;
```

So how to implement this query in

```
$this->db->where($where);
```

???

Comment: there is no way to implement `CASE` in `CI`. CI SQL library is very weak

Comment: Am not sure it is possible in CI. You can go and see what all are available in active rec .. Check this file - system\database\DB_active_rec.php

Comment: read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821503/does-codeigniter-datamapper-orm-support-a-mysql-case-statement-in-order-by-claus

Comment: @diEcho
So if its not possible in codeigniters way then how to implement it in simple way in codeigniter like `$this->db->query('')`??

Comment: `$sql = 'Your complete mySQL query'` and then  `$this->db->query($sql)`

Comment: @diEcho
Already Tried :(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787983/codeigniter-join-and-case-when-query

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in CI.You need to write your own query. Please have a look on this file.You can see all the available methods there.

```
\system\database\DB_active_rec.php
```

Comment: also read the guide : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: So if its not possible in codeigniters way then how to implement it in simple way in codeigniter like $this->db->query('')??