# Codeigniter, Join and Case When Query

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Trying to Execute this query.

```
$sql ="SELECT '*' FROM
            'osp_job_details'
                LEFT JOIN
            'osp_job_status_track' ON 'osp_job_status_track'.'JobID' = 'osp_job_details'.'JobID'
                LEFT JOIN
            'osp_job_status' ON 'osp_job_status'.'StatusID' = 'osp_job_status_track'.'StatusID'
                LEFT JOIN
            'osp_job_sub_status' ON 'osp_job_sub_status'.'SubStatusID' = 'osp_job_status_track'.'SubStatusID'
                LEFT JOIN
            'hr_employee_details' ON 'hr_employee_details'.'EmployeeID' = 'osp_job_details'.'AssignToEmployeeID'
                LEFT JOIN
            'osp_job_type' ON 'osp_job_type'.'JobTypeID' = 'osp_job_details'.'JobtypeID'
            WHERE 'isDefault' = 0 AND

            CASE WHEN 'osp_job_status'.'StatusID' = '2'
            THEN  'osp_job_sub_status'.'CurrentStatus' = '3'
            ELSE 'osp_job_status'.'StatusID' >= '2'
                END;";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
```

But i am getting this below error on running the above query.

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''osp_job_details' LEFT JOIN 'osp_job_status_track'' at line 2

SELECT '*' FROM 'osp_job_details' LEFT JOIN 'osp_job_status_track' ON 'osp_job_status_track'.'JobID' = 'osp_job_details'.'JobID' LEFT JOIN 'osp_job_status' ON 'osp_job_status'.'StatusID' = 'osp_job_status_track'.'StatusID' LEFT JOIN 'osp_job_sub_status' ON 'osp_job_sub_status'.'SubStatusID' = 'osp_job_status_track'.'SubStatusID' LEFT JOIN 'hr_employee_details' ON 'hr_employee_details'.'EmployeeID' = 'osp_job_details'.'AssignToEmployeeID' LEFT JOIN 'osp_job_type' ON 'osp_job_type'.'JobTypeID' = 'osp_job_details'.'JobtypeID' WHERE 'isDefault' = 0 AND CASE WHEN 'osp_job_status'.'StatusID' = '2' THEN 'osp_job_sub_status'.'CurrentStatus' = '3' ELSE 'osp_job_status'.'StatusID' >= '2' END;

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\zorkif_new\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Can Anyone tell what is wrong in my query and how to solve it?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Update:

Removed the Single Quotes

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM
    osp_job_details
        LEFT JOIN
    osp_job_status_track ON osp_job_status_track.JobID = osp_job_details.JobID
        LEFT JOIN
    osp_job_status ON osp_job_status.StatusID = osp_job_status_track.StatusID
        LEFT JOIN
    osp_job_sub_status ON osp_job_sub_status.SubStatusID = osp_job_status_track.SubStatusID
        LEFT JOIN
    hr_employee_details ON hr_employee_details.EmployeeID = osp_job_details.AssignToEmployeeID
        LEFT JOIN
    osp_job_type ON osp_job_type.JobTypeID = osp_job_details.JobtypeID
    WHERE isDefault = 0 AND

    CASE WHEN osp_job_status.StatusID = 2
    THEN  osp_job_sub_status.CurrentStatus = 3
    ELSE osp_job_status.StatusID >= 2
        END;";
```

But getting this below error now..

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'isDefault` = 1 AND CASE WHEN `osp_job_status`.`StatusID` = 2 THEN `osp_job' at line 8

SELECT `osp_job_details`.*, `osp_job_type`.`JobTypeName`, `status`, `Substatus`, `osp_job_status`.`StatusID`, `osp_job_sub_status`.`SubStatusID`, `FirstName`, `MiddleNames`, `LastName`, `hr_employee_details`.`EmployeeID`, `osp_job_status_track`.`StatusTrackID` FROM (`osp_job_details`) LEFT JOIN `osp_job_status_track` ON `osp_job_status_track`.`JobID` = `osp_job_details`.`JobID` LEFT JOIN `osp_job_status` ON `osp_job_status`.`StatusID` = `osp_job_status_track`.`StatusID` LEFT JOIN `osp_job_sub_status` ON `osp_job_sub_status`.`SubStatusID` = `osp_job_status_track`.`SubStatusID` LEFT JOIN `hr_employee_details` ON `hr_employee_details`.`EmployeeID` = `osp_job_details`.`AssignToEmployeeID` LEFT JOIN `osp_job_type` ON `osp_job_type`.`JobTypeID` = `osp_job_details`.`JobtypeID` WHERE ` ` isDefault` = 1 AND CASE WHEN `osp_job_status`.`StatusID` = 2 THEN `osp_job_sub_status`.`CurrentStatus` = 3 ELSE `osp_job_status`.`StatusID` >= 2 END ;

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\zorkif_new\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Comment: why using `*`, it will retrieves 6 tables all columns. specify the columns which you want to retrieve

Comment: change `'` ( single quote )  to `\`` ( sign under the `~` ) from all table or column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use alias to simplify

```
$sql ="SELECT [specific column names ] FROM `osp_job_details` jd
    LEFT JOIN
            `osp_job_status_track` jst ON (`jst`.`JobID` = `jd`.`JobID`)
    LEFT JOIN
            `osp_job_status` js ON (`js`.`StatusID` = `jst`.`StatusID`)
    LEFT JOIN
            `osp_job_sub_status` jss ON (`jss`.`SubStatusID` = `jst`.`SubStatusID`)
    LEFT JOIN
            `hr_employee_details` hed ON (`hed`.`EmployeeID` = `jd`.`AssignToEmployeeID`)
    LEFT JOIN
            `osp_job_type` jt ON (`jt`.`JobTypeID` = `jd`.`JobtypeID`)

    WHERE `isDefault` = '0' 
     AND CASE 
                WHEN `js`.`StatusID` = '2' THEN  `jss`.`CurrentStatus` = '3'
                ELSE `jd`.`StatusID` >= '2'
            END ";
  $this->db->query($qry);
```

**NOTE:** wrap column name and table name with **`**  not with `'` and also when referencing **tablename. column name** exclude the dot `.` from `\`

use  ``tablename``.`` `column_name ```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the quotes around your tables name.

```
SELECT *
FROM osp_job_details
(...)
```

And for what it's worth, you should try using [activerecord](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) for codeigniter. You won't have to worry with the SQL:

```
$this->db
    ->from('osp_job_details')
    ->join('osp_job_status_track', 'osp_job_status_track.JobID = osp_job_details.JobID', 'left')
    ->join('osp_job_status', 'osp_job_status.StatusID = osp_job_status_track.StatusID', 'left')
    ->join('osp_job_sub_status', 'osp_job_sub_status.SubStatusID = osp_job_status_track.SubStatusID', 'left')
    ->join('hr_employee_details', 'hr_employee_details.EmployeeID = osp_job_details.AssignToEmployeeID', 'left')
    ->join('osp_job_type', 'osp_job_type.JobTypeID = osp_job_details.JobtypeID', 'left')
    ->where('isDefault', 0)
    ->where("osp_job_status.StatusID = '2' AND osp_job_sub_status.CurrentStatus = '3' OR osp_job_status.StatusID >= '2'")
    ->result();
```

And if it doesn't work, add brackets around your `CASE WHEN` ;)

Comment: Case When is not supported by CI.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the single quotes :

```
SELECT * FROM
            osp_job_details
                LEFT JOIN
            osp_job_status_track ON osp_job_status_track.JobID = osp_job_details.JobID
                LEFT JOIN
            osp_job_status ON osp_job_status.StatusID = osp_job_status_track.StatusID
                LEFT JOIN
            osp_job_sub_status ON osp_job_sub_status.SubStatusID = osp_job_status_track.SubStatusID
                LEFT JOIN
            hr_employee_details ON hr_employee_details.EmployeeID = osp_job_details.AssignToEmployeeID
                LEFT JOIN
            osp_job_type ON osp_job_type.JobTypeID = osp_job_details.JobtypeID
            WHERE isDefault = 0 AND

            CASE WHEN osp_job_status.StatusID = 2
            THEN  osp_job_sub_status.CurrentStatus = 3
            ELSE osp_job_status.StatusID >= 2
                END;
```

If you want to escape the table names and fields you can use like "`"

**UPDATE:** replace the case :

```
CASE WHEN osp_job_status.StatusID = 2
THEN  osp_job_sub_status.CurrentStatus = 3
ELSE osp_job_status.StatusID >= 2
    END;
```

with:

```
(
    (
        osp_job_status.StatusID = 2
        AND
        osp_job_sub_status.CurrentStatus = 3
    )
    OR
    osp_job_status.StatusID >= 2
)
```

Comment: Updated my question, i removed all the single quotes but still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

In your query you are using `''` single quota in table name and column name by which it is treated as a string so replace the single quota with the `` tag.

Here is replaced code:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM
            `osp_job_details`
                LEFT JOIN
            `osp_job_status_track` ON `osp_job_status_track`.`JobID` = `osp_job_details`.`JobID`
                LEFT JOIN
            `osp_job_status` ON `osp_job_status`.`StatusID` = `osp_job_status_track`.`StatusID`
                LEFT JOIN
            `osp_job_sub_status` ON `osp_job_sub_status`.`SubStatusID` = `osp_job_status_track`.`SubStatusID`
                LEFT JOIN
            `hr_employee_details` ON `hr_employee_details`.`EmployeeID` = `osp_job_details`.`AssignToEmployeeID`
                LEFT JOIN
            `osp_job_type` ON `osp_job_type`.`JobTypeID` = `osp_job_details`.`JobtypeID`
            WHERE `isDefault` = 0 AND

            CASE WHEN `osp_job_status`.`StatusID` = '2'
            THEN  `osp_job_sub_status`.`CurrentStatus` = '3'
            ELSE `osp_job_status`.`StatusID` >= '2'
                END;";
```

Comment: I updated my question, in your case i am getting the second error which i have put in my update.?

Comment: @SyedHaiderHassan check your query again and then execute it. perhaps you have leave any space or you need to add the table name with the column name isDefault.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Simply Add This Condition in your where clause**
**CORE QUERY**

```
(CASE
        WHEN
            tbl_account.account_type = 4
        THEN
            1
   ELSE
     `tbl_acc_company`.`acc_comp_status` = 'ACTIVE'
   END
)
```

**CI QUERY**

```
$this->db->where("(CASE WHEN tbl_account.account_type = 4 THEN  1 ELSE tbl_acc_company.acc_comp_status = 'ACTIVE' END)");
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of what I did to solve a problem in my system that needed a case, and the codeigniter inserted the **`** in the query and returned an error. My solution was to put the *parentheses* => **()** in the case.

`$this->db->select("(case when c.my_column THEN c.my_column ELSE c.other_column END as my_column_name)")`