# Codeigniter : Error in ORDER BY CASE query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, case

Here is my query in **Codeigniter**

```
$this->db->select('p.*,u.firstname, u.lastname,s.title AS industry, pt.type_name , al.length_value',FALSE);
$this->db->from($this->_tbl_projects . ' as p');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_client_details . ' as c', 'c.id = p.client_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_users . ' as u', 'u.id = c.user_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_project_types . ' as pt', 'pt.project_type_id = p.project_type_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_specializations . ' as s', 's.specialization_id = p.specialization_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_article_length . ' as al', 'al.article_length_id = p.article_length_id', 'left');
$this->db->order_by("CASE p.submit_to
                                    WHEN '' THEN 0
                                    WHEN 'writer' THEN 1
                                    ELSE 2
                                END, p.request_end_date asc",FALSE);
```

It Print out

```
SELECT p.*, u.firstname, u.lastname, s.title AS industry, pt.type_name, al.length_value 
FROM (`projects` as p) 
LEFT JOIN `client_details` as c ON `c`.`id` = `p`.`client_id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` as u ON `u`.`id` = `c`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `project_types` as pt ON `pt`.`project_type_id` = `p`.`project_type_id` 
LEFT JOIN `specializations` as s ON `s`.`specialization_id` = `p`.`specialization_id` 
LEFT JOIN `article_length` as al ON `al`.`article_length_id` = `p`.`article_length_id` WHERE `p`.`client_id` = '26' AND `p`.`status` IN (2, 3) 
ORDER BY 
        `CASE` p.submit_to 
            WHEN '' THEN 0 
            WHEN 'writer' THEN 1 
            ELSE 2 
         END, `p`.`request_end_date` asc
```

Here in printed query, **CASE** is printed by **`CASE`**, so sql throws error.

How can I solve it?

Structure of submit_to field is

```
  submit_to enum('','writer','students') NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 8):

The CodeIgniter documentation indicates case statements within the order by clause isn't supported within the Active Record class. I'd recommend refactoring the SQL call so that the case statement is part of the select clause. Something like the following should do the trick.

```
$this->db->select("p.*,u.firstname, u.lastname,s.title AS industry, pt.type_name, al.length_value, CASE p.submit_to WHEN 'writer' THEN 2 WHEN 'students' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ordered_submit_to",FALSE);
$this->db->from($this->_tbl_projects . ' as p');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_client_details . ' as c', 'c.id = p.client_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_users . ' as u', 'u.id = c.user_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_project_types . ' as pt', 'pt.project_type_id = p.project_type_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_specializations . ' as s', 's.specialization_id = p.specialization_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_article_length . ' as al', 'al.article_length_id = p.article_length_id', 'left');
$this->db->order_by('ordered_submit_to', 'ASC');
$this->db->order_by('p.request_end_date', 'ASC');
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your updates works but not gives result in proper order. I want data in order to submit_to = '' then submit_to = 'students' and last submit_to = 'writer'.
Your updates gives result in this order 
1. ''
2. 'writer'
3. 'students'.

Comment: Updated to match your restated order.

Answer (score 6):

I found a good solution in [another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955632/661550) so in case you've landed on this page and haven't found that one, I'll re-post it here.

---

You are able to use a case statement if you **wrap the case statement in parentheses**.

```
$this->db->order_by("
    (CASE p.submit_to
        WHEN '' THEN 0
        WHEN 'writer' THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END), 
    p.request_end_date asc"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out how to avoid escaping **CASE** word.

You can modify **$_reserved_identifiers** variable inside *CI_DB_driver* class. If you don't want to modify whole file, you can simply change it inside your Model class just before that query.

```
$this->db->_reserved_identifiers = array('*','CASE');

$this->db->select('p.*,u.firstname, u.lastname,s.title AS industry, pt.type_name , al.length_value',FALSE);
$this->db->from($this->_tbl_projects . ' as p');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_client_details . ' as c', 'c.id = p.client_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_users . ' as u', 'u.id = c.user_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_project_types . ' as pt', 'pt.project_type_id = p.project_type_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_specializations . ' as s', 's.specialization_id = p.specialization_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_article_length . ' as al', 'al.article_length_id = p.article_length_id', 'left');
$this->db->order_by("CASE p.submit_to
                                WHEN '' THEN 0
                                WHEN 'writer' THEN 1
                                ELSE 2
                            END, p.request_end_date asc",FALSE);
```

(I don't know if it's working on 3.x branch. It's working good on 2.x branch)

Answer (score 0):

I tested today and it's working.

You can use it like you said whenever you use the second parameter FALSE to disable escaping.

```
$this->db->order_by("CASE p.submit_to
                                    WHEN '' THEN 0
                                    WHEN 'writer' THEN 1
                                    ELSE 2
                                END, p.request_end_date asc",FALSE);
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Set your "CASE WHEN" inside your "SELECT" and not inside the "ORDER_BY":

```
$this->db->select('p.*,u.firstname, u.lastname,s.title AS industry, pt.type_name , al.length_value',FALSE);
$this->db->select("CASE p.submit_to WHEN '' THEN 0 WHEN 'writer' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END order_column_number",FALSE);
$this->db->from($this->_tbl_projects . ' as p');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_client_details . ' as c', 'c.id = p.client_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_users . ' as u', 'u.id = c.user_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_project_types . ' as pt', 'pt.project_type_id = p.project_type_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_specializations . ' as s', 's.specialization_id = p.specialization_id', 'left');
$this->db->join($this->_tbl_article_length . ' as al', 'al.article_length_id = p.article_length_id', 'left');
$this->db->order_by("order_column_number ASC, p.request_end_date ASC");
```