# Order by case when is not applicable for code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Order by case when is not applicable for  code igniter. what is the alternate solution please some one try to help me?

Eg : Plain query :

```
SELECT *
FROM `advertise`
JOIN `advertise_catagory` ON `advertise_catagory`.`ad_id` = `advertise`.`ad_id`
JOIN `ad_content` ON `advertise`.`ad_id` = `ad_content`.`ad_id`
JOIN `location` ON `advertise`.`ad_id` = `location`.`ad_id`
JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`cat_id` = `advertise_catagory`.`category`
JOIN `advertise_sub_category_details` ON `advertise_sub_category_details`.`a_cat_id` = `advertise_catagory`.`a_cat_id`
WHERE `location`.`latitude` > 12.955601183225
  AND `location`.`latitude` < 13.045533216775
  AND `location`.`longitude` > 77.628496686798
  AND `location`.`longitude` < 77.720794513202
  AND `status_id` = '4'
  AND `advertise_sub_category_details`.`sub_cat_id` IN('3')
  AND `advertise_catagory`.`category` = '1' **
ORDER BY CASE
             WHEN `advertise`.`locality` ='KR Puram, Krishnarajapuram, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India' THEN -1000
             ELSE ABS(location.latitude - 13.0005672) + ABS(location.longitude - 77.6746456)
         END ASC** LIMIT 500.
```

Comment: @PathikVejani i have updated the plain query please check it.

Comment: You mean `order by` clause is not applicable in codeigniter ?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059814/codeigniter-error-in-order-by-case-query

Comment: @MurtazaBhurgri not ORDER BY  its ORDER BY CASE is there in plain query that only it's not applicable.

Comment: @jtheman thanks for given link but that one i'm already tried it's not working....

Comment: @user3132122 for your information `CASE` is a separate clause, there is no any `ORDER BY CASE` clause, let me read the query.

Comment: ` AND advertise_catagory.category = '1' ** ` what is  **  ??

Comment: @PraveenKumar ** for highlighting the lines in stackoverflow.

Comment: I know about stack overflow but what they are doing in your query(what i meant earlier ) ??

Comment: @user3132122 If i would be you i will add an `extra_column` to the query with your case statement and then Order by `extra_column` ASC then i will see what happened to my `extra_column`. Hope you got it... :)