# Set "speeds" of mysql updates (and inserts) with CodeIgniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter, mariadb, codeigniter-3

In a update i'm working with it's a

```
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY table
```

What we have been using before is an override in the database class protect_identifiers, it typically looks like this

```
$this->db->_reserved_identifiers = array('*', 'LOW_PRIORITY');
```

It seems to be the way to roll up until CI3. 
[Codeigniter : Error in ORDER BY CASE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059814/codeigniter-error-in-order-by-case-query/37460668#37460668) (basicly the same problem)

In CI2 when you called

```
$this->db->_reserved_identifiers = array('*', 'LOW_PRIORITY')
```

The piece of code i was trying to execute would generate

```
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY table set ...
```

but in CI3 it would generate

```
UPDATE 'LOW_PRIORITY' 'table' set ...
```

(it basicly tries to escape it it seems. )

Now the protect_identifiers var is protected, and I can't really update it from the outside without extending the db-class. I really don't want to do this as this seems to be my only "unsolvable" problem after the CI update.

Is it possible to handle this in a different manner?

This is what i'm trying to do

```
if($exist){
    if($this->db->update('LOW_PRIORITY table', $allMyDatas)
    /* 
     * Should print something like 
     * UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY table 
     * SET field = 'fielddata' WHERE something = 'something'
     */
} else {
    if($this->db->insert('LOW_PRIORITY table', $allMyDatas)
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem with actual use of `protect_identifiers()`? By the way, your call doesn't seem right, this function's signature goes like this: `protect_identifiers($item, $prefix_single = FALSE, $protect_identifiers = NULL, $field_exists = TRUE)`. Seems like I'm misinterpreting your goal

Comment: My fault! Added the wrong piece of code. It's not the protect_identifiers, i tried to do some magic with it. The actual problem is with setting     
$this->db->_reserved_identifiers = array('*', 'LOW_PRIORITY');
Updated the question aswell.

Comment: I've added an answer. Hope this helps. I can provide basic examples if you want. It's just I don't have CI3 installation at hand at the moment to give you actual working code for you problem, but it doesn't seem to be hard to apply

Comment: basic examples would be great! Even without the CI3 context

Answer (score 0):

There are two "hacks"(?) that I know of that allow you to access such protected/private properties at runtime: reflection and closures.

Reflection documentation says everything for itself. Closures seems to be a bit more hacky way, but it's actually faster than reflection in this case. `Closure#bind()` allows you to get into the scope of a given object and access it from there, so to say.

Here's dummy example, but it should give you pretty good idea:

```
class Foo { protected $var = 'protected'; }

$foo = new Foo();
var_dump($foo); // $var value is 'protected'
$fun = function(Foo $obj) { $obj->var = 'unprotected'; };
$closure = Closure::bind($fun, null, $foo);
$closure($foo);
var_dump($foo); // $var value is now 'unprotected'
```

Comment: I havn't dealt with reflection or closures as far as i know before, i will try to see if this could solve my problem though :)

Comment: Added an example. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it seems as CI just want us developers to do something else than use the query builder, so i'll just close this as not intended or something.

Comment: Well, not surprising, but worth a try. Extending base class seems like most reasonable solution anyway, minding CI3's architecture. And it can be very "non-invasive" as core overrides/extensions can be stored separately and used only when called for

Answer (score 0):

Closed as developers shouldn't do it like this. Reference the issues section in CI github.

Answer (score 0):

`LOW PRIORITY` is an old clause for MyISAM tables.  You are (or should be) using InnoDB, which has no need for such.  Please elaborate on the desire for such; we can then discuss why you don't need it and/or workarounds.

Comment: There is no reason for me to change my db structure. I feel that that is the wrong answer to the wrong problem. MyISAM was selected for usage because of speed issues with InnoDB (it was just not fast enough). There are those 1 percent of cases, when InnoDB should not be used. There might be better right now, but this is not a new application I'm writing today